# Resorting columns to initial ordering after deletion of columns

Tags: r, matrix, data-management

Clumsy title, but let me explain what's in it:

My initial matrix looks like that:

```
kitty <- matrix(  
  c(1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2), 
  nrow=3, 
  ncol=4)
```

returning:

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
1  0  0  3
2  0  0  1
4  0  0  2
```

I delete all columns of zeros

```
kitty<- kitty[, colSums(kitty != 0) > 0]
```

as I have to run a particular set of econometrics over the matrix which yields (complete random set of numbers here, important is that columns 2 and 3 are no longer in it and that my methodology does not allow me to name columns either):

```
kitty2 <- matrix(  
  c(2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 8), 
  nrow=3, 
  ncol=2)

X1 X4
2  1
3  3
4  8
```

What is an efficient way (I have hundreds of those matrices) to reset columns back to their initial position, filling the missing columns with NAs or 0s?

```
X1 X2 X3 X4
2  NA NA  1
3  NA NA  3
4  NA NA  8
```

Comment: `kitty` is not created with column names. Are there steps you're skipping in your sample code?

Comment: I just used column names to make clear to the reader which columns are kept. In my code, no column names are allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So frankly I am not so sure that this is particularly efficient, but it is the best way I can think of to do it:

Grab the nonzero indices of `kitty`:

```
indices <- which(colSums(kitty != 0) > 0)
```

And then once you have `kitty2`, refill `kitty` with the values of the columns you changed.

```
kitty[,indices] <- kitty2
kitty
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
   [1,]    2    0    0    1
   [2,]    3    0    0    3
   [3,]    4    0    0    8
```

And then you could leave the columns as zeroes or change them to `NA`.

Comment: `for` loops are not evil in themselves, but consider thinking in a "vectorized" mode: the column-index within `[,]` supports *1 or more* columns, so you can simplify this considerably with `kitty[,indices]`. (This actually applies to any dimension in an `array`, where a `matrix` is just a 2-dim `array`.)

Comment: @r2evans That is a way cleaner way to do it! Thanks, I am going to edit my answer to reflect

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to recreate the removed columns, can you just assign `NA` from the outset?

```
kitty <- matrix(  
  c(1, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 2), 
  nrow=3, 
  ncol=4)
kitty[,!(colSums(kitty) > 0)] <- NA
kitty
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA    3
# [2,]    2   NA   NA    1
# [3,]    4   NA   NA    2
```

Comment: Thanks, but not possible: I am running prcomp over the matrix, not allowing for any NA in the array